# startEditing method for QGraphicsTextItem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

In my code I create a `QGraphicsTextItem` which has the editing flag on.

I want to find a way to make it focused in a way that it shows the caret and allows the user to type — just like when the user clicks on it but from code.

Is there any way to perform this programmatically?

The closest I found is `textItem->grabKeyboad()`, which allows the user to write but does not show the dashed border and the caret is not shown until a key is pressed (no visual clue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clue in the documentation, but this appears to work:

```
textItem->setFocus();
```

Comment: I already tried that and it did not work :\ I'm using Qt 5.1.1. Could you put some example code?

Comment: Hmmm... I wrote a simpler code myself with just that and it worked there (in the original code that formed part of a mouse pressed handler).

Comment: I found it. It works with that. :) It was just that I was unfocusing it calling superclass' `mousePressEvent`.